# VB.net loop takes 8 seconds which I find slow

Tags: vb.net, for-loop, foreach, visual-studio-2015

I posted a question like this before but even with replies I still could not get the code to be any faster. I have now modified the code to what it was and am looking for advice on how to speed my code up.

I have a richtextbox which is 30k lines and I need to replace a block of text when the for each loop reaches a certain line of the richtextbox which contains 30k lines. (If variables are not declared in this code means they are global variables)

Here is my code:

```
Dim counter As Integer = 0
        Dim startcount As Boolean = False
        Dim holdstring As String = ""


        Dim completertb4 As New StringBuilder("")
        Dim completertb4one As New StringBuilder("")
        MsgBox(newrtb.Lines.Count,, "")
        Dim counteroflines As Integer = 1
        For Each line As String In newrtb.Lines

            'MsgBox(counteroflines & "----" & holdstring,, "")

            If line.Contains(richtextboxl0) Then
                startcount = True
                holdstring = vbNewLine & richtextbox3text

            ElseIf startcount = True Then
                If counter = temptextbox3count Then
                    startcount = False
                Else
                    counter += 1
                End If

            ElseIf completertb4.ToString = "" Then
                holdstring = line
            Else
                holdstring = line

            End If

            If counteroflines >= 1 And counteroflines <= 10000 Then

                completertb4.Append(vbNewLine & holdstring & "----" & counteroflines)
            Else

                completertb4one.Append(vbNewLine & holdstring & "----" & counteroflines)
            End If

            counteroflines += 1
        Next
```

Comment: Any chance you could illustrate or provide some sample data?

Comment: I resolved my issue, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I shrank my code from 08:00 Seconds to 00:01 Seconds. From 8 seconds to less than a second.

```
            Dim counter As Integer = 0
        Dim countertrue As Integer = 0
        Dim countintertal As Integer = 0


        Dim newrtbstrarray As String() = newrtb.Lines
        Dim rtb3array As String() = richtextbox3text.Lines

        For Each line As String In newrtbstrarray

            If line.Contains(richtextboxl0) Then
                countertrue = counter
                For Each element As String In rtb3array
                    newrtbstrarray(countertrue) = rtb3array(countintertal)
                    countertrue += 1
                    countintertal += 1
                Next

            End If

            counter += 1
        Next
```